# Calling a custom built VBA function when an Excel cell is changed

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I'd like to preface this question by saying that I am an undergrad in college who knows C++ and has a very rudimentary understanding of VBA.

Now then, as stated in the title I need some help configuring some VBA code for an Excel worksheet so that whenever a cell in a column (specifically the D column) is modified it will automatically update other cells within the same row.

Essentially I want this to work such that when user Bob modifies cell D26 (for example) it will call a custom function I built and insert that code into cell B26 and then repeat with a different function for cell C26.

However, this function needs to be such that if cell D27 is modified it will only modify other cells in row 27, leaving row 26 and prior or subsequent rows alone until such a time as this function is called in D28 and so on.

I'm not entirely sure if this is even possible but I'd be gracious if anybody could help me configure this.

The code I built/scavenged from the internet for my custom function is this: 
http://pastebin.com/RE0V2nrT

The second function I want to call for this project is the =TODAY() function built into Excel.

The code I have scraped together so far for checking if the cell has changed is this:
http://pastebin.com/S5E8cmty

If anybody could help me understand how to write what I'm looking for it would be much appreciated. If you have a different approach to solving the issue I would also love to hear it... as long as you could help me then enact your solution, haha!

Anyways, thanks to anybody who replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [worksheet events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn301178.aspx) available within the Excel namespace. 
For this, you would use the [Change event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx)

If you double click on the worksheet you want to monitor, you can insert a `Worksheet_Change` sub. Then you can use the [intersect function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff835030.aspx) to check if the changed cell was within your range you want to monitor (e.g. D:D).

You can specify which cells you want to change.  Here I just gave an example based on what you asked.  This will put the output of your function into cell B[R] and put the current date into cell C[R].  Note that I'm using the `Now()` function since there is no `Today()` function in VBA. Since this returns both date and time, I'm using the Format function to get just the date.

Just for fun, let's go a little further into the object model and first get the [Worksheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff194464.aspx) to which the target range belongs.  This is not 100% necessary - you could just rely on [ActiveSheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx).  Now, you probably don't need to do this, and it's mostly just for fun, but it's also worth noting that if you were programmatically making changes to this sheet, but had not activated this sheet first (so another sheet was active) and you had not turned off [EnableEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821508.aspx) you would get some strange results :)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Set TargetSheet = Target.Parent
    With TargetSheet
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, .Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
            .Cells(Target.Row, 2) = ExtractWindowsUser()
            .Cells(Target.Row, 4) = Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD")
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

### Explanation

Worksheet change sub is declared like this. The Worksheet objects have pre-defined method stubs for events.  Kind of like an interface, though not listed as an interface in the documentation.  If you think of it in that concept, this is your event handshake.  *See the link I posted above for a list of the worksheet events available.*
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

In the next lines we are getting the worksheet object to which the object named `Target` belongs.  You can see in the sub declaration that `Target` is declared as an object of the type `Range`.  If you check out the Worksheet object (linked above) or the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff838238.aspx) documentation you'll see that the range object is a member of the worksheet object, and the documentation kind of sucks here, but FYI the worksheet object is contained within the [Parent property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff196885.aspx).   *Now, originally I had my code using the ActiveSheet member of the Application object - but I've edited it for the reasons given in my answer above.*

```
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
Set TargetSheet = Target.Parent
```

I use [With Blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to save typing the same Worksheet reference in multiple places.  A With block just lets me access the members of the namespace specified (in this case members of the object `TargetSheet`) by typing `.SomeMember`.  The compiler understands that every reference like this refers to whatever is specified in the opening `With ....` statement.  I personally like this for readability, but I also recommend it for maintenance (change reference one place vs many).  Also having a single reference gives a tiny, insignificant, probably not worth mentioning performance boost over multiple references as well.

`With TargetSheet`

Next we check whether or not `Target` is within the range of cells we want to watch.  The `If....Then` should look familiar enough. For our condition we use the [boolean operator Not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cwcswt4.aspx) to check if the result of the intersect function (linked above) Is [Nothing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx).  The reason we do this is to check if the return is allocated.  If an object is allocated the `Not SomeObject Is Nothing` condition will evaluate to `False`.  If the object is not allocated (i.e. our Intersect function failed to return anything) then the statement evaluates to `True`.  So, from the Intersect function documentation we know that if our return is allocated, the ranges intersect and the intersecting range object was returned.  Thus if we want to know if they intersect, we can just check for the opposite of a failure.

`If Not Application.Intersect(Target, .Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then`

The next lines then just execute some code on cells within the same row as `Target`. We use the [Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff194567.aspx) member of the worksheet object to specify what cells to modify.  Per the documentation, the default property for `Cells` is [Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841096.aspx) which lets us access a range object through a row and column index like this: `.Cells[Row,Column]`.  So, I simply use the row of our `Target` object and the column you wanted (column "A" =1, "B"=2, etc.  You can see this by changing excel properties to R1C1 reference style if you are interested).

`.Cells(Target.Row, 2) = ExtractWindowsUser()`

And I think the [Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx) and Now() functions are pretty well explained in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I would like to pose a quick question though, why did you use "With ActiveSheet" and what does "If Not Application.Intersect" do?

Comment: @Jason - if my answer helped solve your question, please click the check mark next to it to make it green :)  Thanks!

Comment: I'll update my answer to explain those things.  I figured coming from C++ they would be obvious. Hold on a sec...

Comment: Okay, yeah, maybe asking exactly "what are they?" wasn't very indicative of my actual questioning. I think what I oh so poorly phrased right there was supposed to be is: ActiveSheet will make it so that any sheet within the Excel file in which this Worksheet_Change add-in is enabled will be able to use it, right? So sheet2 and sheet1 will automatically update if they detect a change in column D? I'm just curious because I can't quite get the code to work right now. I saved your code as an add-in (.xlam) but it doesn't run when I change a cell in column D. Did I save it correctly?

Comment: Don't save it as an add-in. Go into VBA from excel (Alt+F11), look on the left at the project explorer tree.  See your workbook there?  Click the plus - you will see all the modules within that workbook.  Double-click on the sheet you want to monitor for changes to open that workbook's code module.  Paste the code in there.  See screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/fJEeXd8.png

Comment: As far as your question on ActiveSheet, see the documentation link I posted in my answer for full definition.  But, basically, that is just a quick way to access the Worksheet object that is currently Active  Active, in other words, can be interpreted as "currently has focus in the Excel Application".   `Target` on the other hand *ALWAYS* comes from the worksheet with the event code that is running, regardless of what sheet has focus.  `Target` is a parameter of that subroutine, the application populates this with a range containing the cell(s) on the sheet which triggered the event.

Comment: Okay, I just had to leave my work and wasn't able to implement your method as of yet since I don't have access to any of the files I am trying to target. I'm going to try to work on it at my home laptop but since it is a Mac I'm not entirely sure how well it'll carry over. I am going to try again tomorrow and as soon as I get it working I'll checkmark your answer. Thank you so much for your help on this - luckily I'm not required to do this for my job so I have no eta on this project.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly after I added an End If to correspond to your If statement! Thank you so much!